# ¿Cómo hacer que se muestre una notificación de alerta sobre la pantalla con sweetalert y useState()?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, sweetalert2, state

¡Hola a todos!

Estoy creando una notificación de alerta que cuando le das clic al botón de *enviar* muestre encima de la pantalla el mensaje de notificación. Estoy haciendo esto con *SweetAlert2*, pero por alguna razón no se abre el mensaje.

Aca esta el código completo:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./PasswordReset.css";
import SweetAlert2 from 'react-sweetalert2';

function ResetPassword() {
  
const [SwalMail, swalProps] = useState({});
  
  function MailSended(){
    SwalMail({
      showCloseButton: true,
      html: '<p class="custom-container">Te hemos enviado un correo electronico con las instruccciones para reestablecer tu contraseña </p>',
      icon: 'success',
      iconColor: 'white',
      width: "420",
      background: "#1a9ddf",
      showConfirmButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: "Continuar",
      customClass: {
        confirmButton: "custom-button",
        text: "swal-text",
        icon: "success"
      }
    });
  }

  
  return (
    <body>
      <form class="login">
        <img src={nominom} alt="" />
        <p class="instruction">
          Por favor, ingresa tu mail para enviarte un link de recuperacion de
          contraseña
        </p>
        <div class="inputs">
          <div class="input-wrapper">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="16"
              height="24"
              fill="currentColor"
              class="bi bi-envelope"
              viewBox="0 0 16 16"
            >
              <path d="M0 4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v8a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4Zm2-1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v.217l7 4.2 7-4.2V4a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H2Zm13 2.383-4.708 2.825L15 11.105V5.383Zm-.034 6.876-5.64-3.471L8 9.583l-1.326-.795-5.64 3.47A1 1 0 0 0 2 13h12a1 1 0 0 0 .966-.741ZM1 11.105l4.708-2.897L1 5.383v5.722Z" />
            </svg>
            <input type="email" placeholder="userexample@gmail.com" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={MailSended}>enviar</button>
        <SweetAlert2 {...swalProps}/>
      </form>
    </body>            
    );
}

export { ResetPassword };
```

Estaría muy agradecido si alguien me brindara una ayuda amiga o quizas un consejo.

Gracias y que tengan buen días todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas empleando el valor inicial del useState como una funcion, en lugar de utilizar la función para modificar el estado y pasar el objeto con las propiedad para ser usadas por el componente:

```js
function ResetPassword() {
  const [swalProps, setSwalProps] = useState({}); // AQUI PASAS el valor por defecto. 
 
  function MailSended(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // necesitas agregar esto para evitar que el submit de tu form haga refresh

    setSwalProps(
      {
        show: true,  // DEBES COLOCARLE EL VALOR A SHOW, YA QUE SIN EL NO SE MOSTRARA
        showCloseButton: true,
        html: '<p class="custom-container">Te hemos enviado un correo electronico con las instruccciones para reestablecer tu contraseña </p>',
        icon: 'success',
        iconColor: 'white',
        width: '420',
        background: '#1a9ddf',
        showConfirmButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Continuar',
        customClass: {
          confirmButton: 'custom-button',
          text: 'swal-text',
          icon: 'success',
        },
      });
  }

  return (
    <body>
      <form class="login">
        <img src={''} alt="" />
        <p class="instruction">
          Por favor, ingresa tu mail para enviarte un link de recuperacion de
          contraseña
        </p>
        <div class="inputs">
          <div class="input-wrapper">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="16"
              height="24"
              fill="currentColor"
              class="bi bi-envelope"
              viewBox="0 0 16 16"
            >
              <path d="M0 4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v8a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4Zm2-1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v.217l7 4.2 7-4.2V4a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H2Zm13 2.383-4.708 2.825L15 11.105V5.383Zm-.034 6.876-5.64-3.471L8 9.583l-1.326-.795-5.64 3.47A1 1 0 0 0 2 13h12a1 1 0 0 0 .966-.741ZM1 11.105l4.708-2.897L1 5.383v5.722Z" />
            </svg>
            <input type="email" placeholder="userexample@gmail.com" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={MailSended}>enviar</button>
      </form>
      <SweetAlert2 {...swalProps} />
    </body>
  );
}

export { ResetPassword };
```

Puntos importantes marcados en el código:

- La propiedad `show` debe  estar en true para que tu alerta se muestra de lo contrario no se mostrara
- Posiciona la alerta fuera del formulario ya que no tiene sentido tenerla ahí (Solo por cuestiones estructurales)
- Evita que tu formulario haga refresh!